# It is impossible to import/install Basemap

Tags: matplotlib-basemap

I have tried everything to import basemap and I really need it. Can somebody fix my problem.

Here is the error I got.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-ad7506b589db> in <module>
      9 from matplotlib import path
     10 import os, glob
---> 11 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
     12 import pandas as pd
     13 from pylab import *

~/miniconda3/envs/venv1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py in <module>
     48 from matplotlib.image import imread
     49 import sys, os, math
---> 50 from .proj import Proj
     51 import numpy as np
     52 import numpy.ma as ma

~/miniconda3/envs/venv1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/proj.py in <module>
      4 import pyproj
      5 import math
----> 6 from matplotlib.cbook import dedent
      7
      8 __version__ = '1.2.2'

ImportError: cannot import name 'dedent' from 'matplotlib.cbook' (/deneme/users/cet/miniconda3/envs/venv1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py)
```

I have tried to upgrade and downgrade matplotlib, pip install matplotlib and conda forge..
So, any help would be greatfull.

Comment: Please post your code in addition to what you already have.

Comment: Can you please provide the installed matplotlib and basemap versions. Just a quick google reveals ton of useful links, one of which is https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/494.